# how to code server action for updating multiple records in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

I have a server action that is supposed to fetch the data of the selected records to make a post request to an api.
This is my server action

```xml
<record model="ir.actions.server" id="action_hr_payroll_execute_payroll">
          <field name="name">Execute Payment</field>
          <field name="model_id" ref="hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip"/>
          <field name="binding_model_id" ref="hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip"/>
          <field name="binding_view_types">list</field>
          <field name="state">code</field>
          <field name="code">
             
                records.check_pay_execute()
          </field>
      </record>
```

This is the check_pay_execute function being called

```py
def check_pay_execute(self):
       cheker = 0
       for rec in self:

           if rec.state != 'done':
               raise Warning(_('You cannot process a draft payslip '
                               'for payment'))
           if rec.pay_status != 'approved':
               raise Warning(_('You cannot execute payslip not approved '
                               'for payment'))

           else:
               continue

       return self.execute_payment()
```

And this is the execute_payment function being called

```py
def execute_payment(self):
        self.ensure_one
        print("Execute Payment")
        pay_acquirer = self.env['payment.acquirer']. \
            search([('provider', '=', 'rave')], limit=1)
        _logger.info('Flutter secret key: %s', pay_acquirer.rave_secret_key)
        print("Checking details")
        _logger.info("Getting name %s", self.employee_id.name)
        _logger.info("Getting account number %s", self.employee_id.bank_account_id.acc_number)
        _logger.info("Getting account code %s", self.employee_id.bank_account_id.bic)
        emp_name = self.employee_id.name
        acc_num = self.employee_id.bank_account_id.acc_number
        acc_bank = self.employee_id.bank_account_id.bank_id.bic

        _logger.info("Getting data %s", emp_name)

        data = {
            "account_bank": acc_bank,
            "account_number": acc_num,
            "amount": self.net_wage,
            "seckey": pay_acquirer.rave_secret_key,
            "narration": "New transfer",
            "currency": self.currency_id.name,
            # "reference": ,
            "beneficiary_name": emp_name 
        }

        ## Make transfer to Employee bank details

        api_url = "https://%s/v2/gpx/transfers/create" % \
            (pay_acquirer._get_rave_api_url())
        _logger.info('API URL: %s', api_url)
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    # 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % (pay_acquirer.rave_secret_key)
        }

        _logger.info('Posting to API: \n%s', data)
        r = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
        tree = json.loads(r.text)
        _logger.info("tree: \n%s", tree)
        self.write({'pay_status': 'submitted'})
        
        if tree['status'] == "error":
            raise UserError(_(tree['message']))
        print("Payment submitted")
        return self._rave_validate_tree(tree)
```

When I execute the "Execute Payment" action I get this error:

```
Checking details
> /home/akoh/isodir/odoo/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py(346)safe_eval()
-> raise ValueError('%s: "%s" while evaluating\n%r' % (ustr(type(e)), ustr(e), expr))
```

This shows the error starts after the "Checking details" logger, it seems its not getting the records properly from self. I really don't know what to do or how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Several strange things in your code.

1. ensure_one is a method. You must added () at the end. -> (Probably the error)
2. You action.server is in list view (implied you can worked on multiple record), in your first function you loop on self (until here it's logical) but when you called the next method `execute_payment` You do it with self but the first line of your method `execute_payment` is ensure_one, that make no sense.
3. cheker never used (And I think it's "checker").
4. Your `else: continue` have no sense. You're at the end of your loop.

And FYI

- requests.post have a parameters `json` will automatically encoding your dict.

[More complicated POST requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

- you can simply used `r.json()` to get the response data.

[JSON Response Content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)